# What to do with vinyl flooring on landing where it meets the top of steps?

Tags: flooring

We are installing some Karndean vinyl flooring on a landing. The pictures are of the staircase and the final step. We have installed plywood over the floorboards.

The issue is what to do at the top of the stairs where the vinyl/ply meets the last stair riser ? The stairs are not carpeted, and will later be painted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use a product like a "vinyl floor overlap stair nose".

This term is used at a US-based big-box store and was one of the items that was listed in a search for "vinyl floor transition molding".

There are a gazillion options, it's up you to pick one that works for your flooring choice. Note that you may need to extend the plywood out to the edge of the stair nose to get a flush finish depending on which nosing trim piece you select.

It's likely that the flooring manufacturer will make a nosing trim piece that will match the particular pattern you've chosen, I'd suggest looking through their online catalogue and picking something out. I'm sure you could order it directly or through whomever you bought your flooring from.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like lapped transitions at stairs. That's a really bad place for a trip hazard, and they always seem to be flexible and creaky, which feels cheap.

I'd probably do this:

1. Remove the existing nosing flush with the riser. Your new underlayment should also end flush with the riser.
2. Install a new nosing (or reinstall the removed one) with its top face just a smidgen above the final height of the vinyl. You want it just above because flush joints are usually ugly and because it'll protect the edge of the vinyl. I'm talking 1/16" (~1.5mm) *at the most*.
3. Fit your vinyl to the back face of the nosing.

One challenge you'll have is supporting the nosing well. There can be a lot of load stress on it, so you ideally want to use construction adhesive and long screws into solid framing. Then, glue and nail the cove underneath back into place to act as further support.

Comment: I say to use a lot of construction adhesive, more than you're comfortable with or think it will need. It's better to waste a buck or three on wasted run-out glue than re-doing it 6 months later when they pop off and you have to use even more and chisel away the too-thin coat. don't ask how i know...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own vinyl stair nosing using a piece of the plank, a form and a heat gun.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v627jfPhNBU